# Can altering a computed column definition cause an update trigger to fire?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2016, calculated-columns

Scenario:

1. Table has 1 or more computed columns. Those columns have simple calculations based solely on the values of other columns in the table. Columns are marked as PERSISTED.
2. Table has an AFTER INSERT, UPDATE trigger to INSERT or UPDATE rows to a second table.
3. Second table schema is identical EXCEPT there are no computed columns.
4. After deploy and table use (table now has production data in it), it is determined that the calculation is in error and needs to be corrected.

The developer expected that changing the computed column calculation would cause the trigger to fire (basically a DML operation). What was observed was more like a DDL operation. The source table showed the correct results of the changes to the calculation but the second table did not. The fact that the computed column values were corrected led the dev to conclude that the changes would be reflected in the other table.

It is my assertion that such a table change is similar to altering the type of a column. It is a DDL operation and does not qualify as an operation that would cause a DML trigger to fire. The problem is that I am inferring that result based on experience. I have not found documentation stating that this *should* be the expected result. Can anyone enlighten me?

THank you

Comment: You can't change a computed column though; if you need to you have to `DROP` said column and then re-`ADD` it. Both of these are part of an `ALTER TABLE` statement, which is a DDL statement. A [table] `TRIGGER` occurs after a `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and/or `DELETE` statement on the table it's created on; an `ALTER TABLE` statement is none of these.

Comment: To add to the above, generally what happens if the outcome of an action is not clear is that you *test* it first in development; it would take very little effort to mock up the same scenario (although presumably there is a development server identical to production) and test the outcome of dropping and adding a new computed column, and doing so would show that any trigger on the table would not fire. Said 'developer' needs to learn good practice.

Comment: As you can see, the trigger is not fired https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=100464fa52c61971ddf2591511f6814f

Comment: Better question is why the other table didn't have computed columns also

Comment: @Charlieface The second table does not have the computation because of DRY. It is a waypoint for a specific purpose and is intended only to reflect the content of the original table. Repeating the code means next time it has to be fixed in twice as many places.

Comment: @Stu Agreed. The computed columns predate the secondary table by a period of years. The developer had not had the luxury of wading through a similar change previously as he was very recently an intern. As Engineering and with a pile more experience I was asked why this happened. As I noted my assertion was this is DDL, not DML, similar to changing the type of a column. And while my assertion holds based on the evidence I was hoping for some concrete documentation I have not yet seen.

Comment: @lamu I am aware of that. The issue was not how to change the computation. It was understanding what constitutes pure DDL. I understand how the developer concluded that the change might be reflected in the second table if only based on his limited experience. My assertion is correct based on the evidence. What I was hoping for was direction to some bit of MS documentation that showed this as intentional.

Answer (score 0):

An `alter` to the *table* is not an `update` to the *data*, so a trigger defined to fire on `update` will not fire when an `alter` is executed.

You must refresh the second table:

```
delete from table2;
insert into table2 select * from table1;
```

Comment: Yes, that is what the evidence suggested. I was hoping someone knew of some magic piece of MS documentation that said definitively that something that appears to update data, in fact, does not do so in the way the dev anticipated. At least he'll know if it happens again.

Comment: @Bryant try updating all rows, but make no change to the data: `update table1 set someColumn = someColumn`.

Comment: @Bryant Altering the definition of a DML operation is not itself DML; it's DDL.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation for `CREATE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) it says: *(my bold)*

> Creates a DML, DDL, or logon trigger. A trigger is a special type of stored procedure that automatically runs when an event occurs in the database server. **DML triggers** run when a user tries to modify data through a data manipulation language (DML) event. **DML events are `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` statements on a table or view.** These triggers fire when any valid event fires, whether table rows are affected or not. For more information, **see [DML Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15)**.
>
> **DDL triggers** run in response to a variety of data definition language (DDL) events. These events primarily correspond to Transact-SQL `CREATE`, `ALTER`, and `DROP` statements, and certain system stored procedures that perform DDL-like operations.

And in that linked article [it says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15#types-of-dml-triggers):

> **Types of DML Triggers**
>
> `AFTER` trigger
> `AFTER` triggers are executed after the action of **the `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `MERGE`, or `DELETE` statement** is performed....

As you can see clearly, the *only* actions which fire DML triggers are those for statements. `ALTER` instead fires DDL triggers, which are very different.

And you can see from this quick mock-up in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=100464fa52c61971ddf2591511f6814f) that that is the case.

Comment: I am well aware of how triggers work and the difference between DDL and DML and have been since v6. Can you bold for me where it says that a DML operation (executing the calculation in a computed column is a DML operation) that appears to change data (which is generally a DML operation and you can see it happen in SSMS), is in fact not a DML operation so I should not expect a DML-based trigger to execute? It is THAT specific documentation I am seeking for the benefit of the recent intern.

Comment: I am completely confused about what you are saying. How can you update a computed column? See this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cb167de3fb66399ad4b05435f4881f1. "Executing a computed column" I presume then that you mean to `SELECT` it, why would that be DML? It doesn't change any data, it's just a calculation. What changes in SSMS? Only updating the base columns would change it. The operations you are using to modify the computed column definition are `ALTER` statements, which I showed are explicitly *not* DML statements and do not fire DML triggers

Comment: A computed column 'value' changes when the value of the column(s) on which it is based is altered. I assumed that was clear. If a computed column is based on the addition of 2 other columns then you can observe in SSMS (or other tool of your choice) that a change to the underlying columns alters the value of the computed column. Given that the calculation that defines the computed column is defined as a DML operation, idiots like me might conclude it to be a DML operation. All I am looking for is the documentation that explains that this is not a DML operation.

Comment: Sorry, I was under the impression you were running `DROP` and `ADD` to change the computed column definition. That would not be DML, as I have shown, as it is not one of those four operations. If you are doing `UPDATE` against the base column then yes that **is** a DML operation and *would* fire the trigger. What was actually executed?